# Why is iPhoto for iOS is "updating photo library" so slowly every time I open it?

Tags: ios, photos.app

Every time I open iPhoto on the iPad, I get an "updating photo library" dialog that sometimes takes minutes to process.

I often get it again after editing and sharing a photo within the app.   I *do* have a large number of photos on the device - probably close to 10k, but other photo apps seem perfectly capable of opening my photos and loading a given album when I select it.  iPhoto seems to need to rebuild the entire database at every open. Most of the time, almost nothing has changed (safe for a handful of new photostream pics.

**Is this a direct function of the number of pics on the device?**

**Is there a setting I can disable?** (It's occurred to me that the "find similar photos" feature, which I dont' care about, could be why it's working so hard at every open.

If I wanted something that took a half hour to boot up, I'd buy an adobe product.

Comment: Have you tried removing and re-installing the app?

Comment: @Michiel, I did, and think it helped a little, but the start time is still pretty much untenable for a mobile app.

Comment: +1 for the Adobe crack; and also because I am having the same problem.